# define a 3d numpy array with a range in column-wise format

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, matrix, multidimensional-array

I want to define a 3d numpy array with shape = [3, 3, 5] and also with values as a range starting with 11 and step = 3 in column-wise manner. I mean:

```
B[:,:,0] = [[ 11,  20,  29],
            [ 14,  23,  32],
            [17,   26,  35]]

B[:,:,1] = [[ 38,  ...],
            [ 41,  ...],
            [ 44,  ...]]
...
```

I am new to numpy and I doubt doing it with `np.arange` or `np.mgrid` maybe. but I don't how to do.

How can this be done with minimal lines of code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can calculate the end of the range by multiplying the shape by the step and adding the start. Then it's just reshape and transpose to move the column around:

```
start = 11
step = 3
shape = [5, 3, 3]

end = np.prod(shape) * step + start

B = np.arange(start, end, step).reshape([5, 3, 3]).transpose(2, 1, 0)
B[:, :, 0]

# array([[11, 20, 29],
#        [14, 23, 32],
#        [17, 26, 35]])
```